# jquery focus() and blur() don't work for my href. why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, focus

i have a link in my html:

```
<a id="mnRoles" href="SysRoles.aspx">Roles</a>
```

here is more html:

```
<tr><td style="vertical-align:top;width:33%;">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="MenuTable">
<tr><th>HRM</th></tr>
<tr><td><a id="mnRoles" href="SysRoles.aspx">Roles</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a id="mnFunctions" href="SysFunctions.aspx">Function rights</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a id="mnRegionalOptions" href="MenuCustomize.aspx">Regional options</a></td>    </tr>
</table></td></tr></table>

<script>sysPageUrl='logposmanagement.aspx'</script></form>

</body>
</html>
```

and i'm trying to set focus to it (or blur another one) through jQuery like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mnRoles").blur();
    $("#mnFunction").focus();
});
</script>
```

but it doesn't work. any ideea why? thanks in advance!

(the reason i'm asking this: i want the focus to be set to a specific link of my choice when the page is loaded (through jQuery. i can't modify any html or css). could someone please help? thanks!)

Comment: Please post more code, espically more relevant html code.

Comment: You're focusing then unfocusing... so you're not focusing. (You can't see it)

Comment: @Ali Bassam: He is unfocusing a different element, so this is not the problem.

Comment: @Horea: The chunk you posted in your question **does** work (as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/PtLL4/), so the problem lies in some part of the code you aren't posting.

Comment: i posted all the relevant html code. i don't think it matters that this is inside a table or not. anyway here it is:

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="MenuTable">
    <tr><th>HRM</th></tr>
    <tr><td><a id="mnRoles" href="SysRoles.aspx">Roles</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a id="mnFunctions" href="SysFunctions.aspx">Function rights</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a id="mnRegionalOptions" href="MenuCustomize.aspx">Regional     options</a></td>    </tr>
        </table></td></tr></table>

Comment: Update your answer instead of adding code in a comment, please !

Comment: it doesn't work for me in Mozilla, Chrome, Safari :(

Comment: i can't post an answer for the first 8 hours, only post a comment: "Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer in 7 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead."

Comment: Don't post an **answer**. **Edit** the _question_ instead.

Comment: It worked for me, check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/F8L5J/). Howevery, why you need to focus your link?

Comment: The question is WHY do you want to focus it? Tab index could be set tp 1 or to make it stand out? (use css/classname)

Comment: Your link has id `mnFunctions`, but in jQuery, you want to access it with `mnFunction` (you omitted the `s`).

Comment: im working on a multibrowser project, and i have to make a page look identically to another one (and on that page, that first link is focused when you land on the page, and i have to do that also through jquery)

Answer (score 1):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F8L5J/)**

Your link is:

```
<a id="mnFunctions" href="SysFunctions.aspx">Function rights</a>
```

Note that the id is `mnFunctions`, but in your jQuery code, you wrote:

```
$("#mnFunction").focus();
```

Here, the id is `mnFunction`. You omitted the `s` at the end. You must write this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mnRoles").blur();
    $("#mnFunctions").focus(); // note that the ID has an `s` at the end
});
```

- You can check the [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F8L5J/).

Comment: thanks, but i tried all the ID's there, from there the mistake. but it doesn't work on chrome/firefox/safari. (when i enter the page, the focus is automatically on the first link mnRoles)

Comment: Yes, it works for me on Chrome and IE, but not in Firefox `:|`. add `tabindex="1"` to your desire link and give me the result `:)` (remove the js).

Comment: i can't modify the html code :( any other ideea? thanks a lot :)